# Can you find an interpretation of the following arithmetical function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, complex-numbers, mobius-function

For integers $n\geq 1$, taking $k\geq 1$ for 
$$z_k:=\mu(k)+i,$$
where $\mu(k)$ is the **Möbius function** and $i=\sqrt{-1}$ the **complex imaginay unit**, then we define the (real) arithmetical function 
$$f(n)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \left|  z_k \right|^2- \left( 1+\frac{6}{\pi^2} \right)  \left( \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} z_k \right)\cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bar{ z}_k \right)- \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( \frac{z_k+\bar{ z}_k}{2} \right)^2 \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
where we are denoting the complex conjugate of a complex number with $\bar{ z}$.

> **Question.** I'm not looking a simplification of such arithmetical function, neither its properties. Those what I am asking is if **you can deduce an interpretation, or you known it from the literature**, without a simplification of such arithmetical function (see my **Attempts**). **Thanks in advance.**

I am interested, if the (arithmetical function) $(z_k)_{k\geq 1}$ was in the literature, looking to get closed form as previous arithmetical function $f(n)$. I am interested in such $f(n)$, since in the literature there is a condition (an asymptotic identity) involving, now yes,  its simplified form (but I don't can provide us an open acess of such condition, and this isn't myself question).

*If it isn't possible, I understand that myself is a speculative way (in my attempts my claims I am asking to me about an explanation that perhaps there no exists and about the importance...), and there aren't answers I should delete my post in the next weeks*.

**Attempts.** Each one of my attempts were uncompleted, I am looking an explanation of why the  artificious defined $f(n)$ could be useful to study the distribution of the values of $\mu(n)$. We have also that $f(n)$ is positive and unbounded (but it isn't the explanation or relation that I am looking; I am looking a special meaning of such $f(n)$).

**The first** one (I hope that my few words have sense), is that we claim that  $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic with the plane $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, and the **lattice points** (the Möbius function always take integers values), and I am looking an explanation or notion that provide us the importance of the distribution of $(z_k)_{k\geq 1}$ as subset of the lattice. And we have that $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ is the **density of the lattice points that are visible from the origin**, and
$$\frac{6}{\pi^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z_k+\bar{ z}_k}{2k^2},$$
but it doesn't say nothing to me about why the shape of the function $f(n)$ is special, from the distribution of $(z_k)_{k\geq 1}$ as subset of the lattice.

**My second** attempt was think about **statistics**, where the squares, **sum of squares, differences** and the square root are importants to analyze a (random) sample $(z_k)_{k=1}^n$ (in this point I known, and I hope that my words are right that statistics is based in the theory of $\mathcal{l}^2(F)$ spaces, thus we are working with one of them, over the field $F= \mathbb{C} $ ). I knonw about the **variance**, and other definitions, but I don't know if I can get a explanation from those. Since in this attempt the squares have importance, I can write this time, $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ as $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$, where as we know $\zeta(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$. And perhaps it is possible write $1$, if such interpretation has mathematical meaning, using the sample $z_k$, with $\Re$, $\Im$ or the complex conjugancy.

Comment: In my frist attempt, I was confused when by comparison between the graph of the Möbius function $k+i\mu(k)$ and the points in the lattice $z_k$, that are only three, thus my words have no meaning. I hope some answers in the next two weeks, since I don't know if my question is a good question or ambiguous, after if there aren't answers I should be delete it. Thanks,